# 1976 Land Cruiser fj40 front disc rotor removal

Tags: toyota, brake-rotor

How do I remove front disc rotors. I know how to remove calipers and free wheeling
hubs but not rotors. Is this possible without disassembling the hubs?

Comment: Yes it's need to be diassembling, while at it replace seals and bearing. Videos to help you do it:
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_3CI4mmEv6A
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NlcVwWAAHw8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at this image, it appears the entire thing has to be pulled apart to get to it:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Procedure should be same as it´s shown in this [Utube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EzJEdD-ukrA), I hope it helped.

Boris

Comment: That's actually a pretty informative video.

Comment: I am glad I could help :)

Comment: good advice problem solved